# Resuming from checkpoint, accuracy drops for one cycle

Tags: pytorch

I'm experiencing a weird issue when trying to finetune a model with PyTorch. I've adapted a script similar to `imagenet.py` training script from PyTorch repository. Each time I stop the training, and trying to resume from a checkpoint, I'm seeing a sharp drop in accuracy. After one "save cycle" (mini-epoch?) the accuracy seems to recover, and sometimes is even doing better.

Since the dataset I'm running on is big, I've made changes to log and save on shorter cycles, and so my training loop is a bit different from the original imagenet.py script. This is probably the cause of this bug, but I can't figure out what this might be.

[image: accuracy drops when resuming training]

```py
    import os 
    import shutil 
    import time

    import torch from tensorboard_logger 
    import log_value

    def train(train_dataset, train_loader, model, criterion, optimizer, val_loader, best_prec1, best_train_prec1, samples, checkpoint_directory, args, scheduler):
        """Train for one epoch on the training set"""
        batch_time = AverageMeter()
        losses = AverageMeter()
        top1 = AverageMeter()

        # switch to train mode
        model.train()

        end = time.time()
        for i, (input, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
            if scheduler is not None:
                scheduler.batch_step()
            target = target.cuda(async=True)
            input = input.cuda()
            input_var = torch.autograd.Variable(input)
            target_var = torch.autograd.Variable(target)

            # compute output
            output = model(input_var)
            loss = criterion(output, target_var)

            # measure accuracy and record loss
            prec1 = accuracy(output.data, target, topk=(1,))[0]
            losses.update(loss.data[0], input.size(0))
            top1.update(prec1[0], input.size(0))
            samples += input.size(0)

            # compute gradient and do SGD step
            loss.backward()
            if i % args.accum == 0:
                optimizer.step()
                optimizer.zero_grad()

            # measure elapsed time
            batch_time.update(time.time() - end)
            end = time.time()

            if i % args.print_freq == 0:
                print('Epoch: {0:.4f}\t'
                      'Step: {1}/{2}\t'
                      'Samples: [{samples}]\t'
                      'LR: {lr}\t'
                      'Time {batch_time.val:.3f} ({batch_time.avg:.3f})\t'
                      'Samples/s {samples_per_sec:.0f}\t'
                      'Loss {loss.val:.4f} ({loss.avg:.4f})\t'
                      'Prec@1 {top1.val:.3f} ({top1.avg:.3f})'.format(
                    samples / len(train_dataset), i, len(train_loader), samples=samples, batch_time=batch_time,
                    samples_per_sec=input.size(0)/batch_time.avg,
                    lr=get_learning_rate(optimizer)[0],# *iter_accum ???
                loss=losses, top1=top1))

            if i % args.save_steps_freq == 0:
                if i>0:
                    # evaluate on validation set
                    prec1 = validate(val_loader, model, criterion, samples, args)

                    # remember best prec@1 and save checkpoint
                    print('Checkpoint')
                    is_best = prec1 > best_prec1
                    best_prec1 = max(prec1, best_prec1)
                    is_best_train = top1.avg > best_train_prec1
                    best_train_prec1 = max(top1.avg, best_train_prec1)
                    save_checkpoint({
                        'samples': samples,
                        'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
                        'best_prec1': best_prec1,
                        'best_train_prec1': best_train_prec1,
                        'train_prec1': top1.avg,
                    }, is_best, is_best_train,
                        directory=checkpoint_directory
                    )

                    # log to TensorBoard
                    log_value('train_loss', losses.avg, samples)
                    log_value('train_acc', top1.avg, samples)
                    log_value('learning_rate', get_learning_rate(optimizer)[0], samples)
                    log_value('batch_size', input.size(0), samples)
                    log_value('effective_batch_size', input.size(0)*args.accum, samples)
                    log_value('accum', args.accum, samples)

                batch_time.reset()
                losses.reset()
                top1.reset()
        return best_prec1, best_train_prec1, samples


    def validate(val_loader, model, criterion, samples, args):
        """Perform validation on the validation set"""
        batch_time = AverageMeter()
        losses = AverageMeter()
        top1 = AverageMeter()

        # switch to evaluate mode
        model.eval()

        end = time.time()
        for i, (input, target) in enumerate(val_loader):
            # print("input={}", input.size())
            target = target.cuda(async=True)
            input = input.cuda()
            input_var = torch.autograd.Variable(input, volatile=True)
            target_var = torch.autograd.Variable(target, volatile=True)

            # compute output
            output = model(input_var)
            # print("validate vars input={} target={} output={}".format(input_var.size(), target_var.size(), output.size()))
            loss = criterion(output, target_var)

            # measure accuracy and record loss
            prec1 = accuracy(output.data, target, topk=(1,))[0]
            losses.update(loss.data[0], input.size(0))
            top1.update(prec1[0], input.size(0))

            # measure elapsed time
            batch_time.update(time.time() - end)
            end = time.time()

            if i % args.print_freq == 0:
                print('Test: [{0}/{1}]\t'
                      'Time {batch_time.val:.3f} ({batch_time.avg:.3f})\t'
                      'Loss {loss.val:.4f} ({loss.avg:.4f})\t'
                      'Prec@1 {top1.val:.3f} ({top1.avg:.3f})'.format(
                    i, len(val_loader), batch_time=batch_time, loss=losses,
                    top1=top1))

        print(' * Prec@1 {top1.avg:.3f}'.format(top1=top1))

        # log to TensorBoard
        log_value('val_loss', losses.avg, samples)
        log_value('val_acc', top1.avg, samples)

        return top1.avg


    def get_learning_rate(optimizer):
        if optimizer is None:
            return [0.0]
        lr=[]
        for param_group in optimizer.param_groups:
            lr +=[ param_group['lr'] ]
        return lr


    def save_checkpoint(state, is_best, is_best_train, directory, filename='checkpoint.pth.tar'):
        """Saves checkpoint to disk"""
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)
        filename = directory + filename
        torch.save(state, filename)
        if is_best:
            shutil.copyfile(filename, directory + 'model_best.pth.tar')
        if is_best_train:
            shutil.copyfile(filename, directory + 'model_best_train.pth.tar')


    class AverageMeter(object):
        """Computes and stores the average and current value"""

        def __init__(self):
            self.reset()

        def reset(self):
            self.val = 0
            self.avg = 0
            self.sum = 0
            self.count = 0

        def update(self, val, n=1):
            self.val = val
            self.sum += val * n
            self.count += n
            self.avg = self.sum / self.count


    def adjust_learning_rate(optimizer, epoch, lr):
        """Sets the learning rate to the initial LR decayed by 10 after 150 and 225 epochs"""
        lr = lr * (0.1 ** (epoch // 150)) * (0.1 ** (epoch // 225))
        # log to TensorBoard
        log_value('learning_rate', lr, epoch)
        for param_group in optimizer.param_groups:
            param_group['lr'] = lr


    def accuracy(output, target, topk=(1,)):
        """Computes the precision@k for the specified values of k"""
        maxk = max(topk)
        batch_size = target.size(0)

        _, pred = output.topk(maxk, 1, True, True)
        pred = pred.t()
        correct = pred.eq(target.view(1, -1).expand_as(pred))

        res = []
        for k in topk:
            correct_k = correct[:k].view(-1).float().sum(0)
            res.append(correct_k.mul_(100.0 / batch_size))
        return res
```

Answer (score 1):

My hunch is that this is due to losing the optimizer state. You're only preserving the model weights, the optimizer has to re-learn the momentum.